# Cannot receive (or send?) Push notifications for Android after migrating to parse-server on Heroku

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

Everytime a push is sent to an Android client I get the following:

03-22 17:15:21.751 1585-2213/? I/GCM: GCM message  0:1458663322082941%5774d2def9fd7ecd
03-22 17:15:21.803 1585-1585/? W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg= (has extras) }

I added all necessary permissions and metadata to the manifest file. I had no problems receiving push notifications (sent via cloud code or REST API) prior to migrating.

Did someone experience that, too, and have you found a solution for it?

Edit:
Code from manifest file:

...

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.unicorn.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".functions.CustomParseBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

...

custom BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class CustomParseBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
protected void onPushReceive(Context context,
                                 Intent intent) {....
```

Edit: This is what a document in the _PushStatus collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "some-other-id"
    },
    "objectId": "some-id",
    "pushTime": "2016-03-19T17:51:12.235Z",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2016-03-19T17:51:12.235Z"
    },
    "query": "{\"deviceType\":{\"$in\":[\"ios\",\"android\"]}}",
    "payload": {
        "title": "The Shining",
        "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
    },
    "source": "rest",
    "title": null,
    "expiry": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "numSent": 0,
    "pushHash": "f41355801d168ad58b479075e9a8576e",
    "_wperm": [],
    "_rperm": [],
    "numFailed": 0
}
```

So numSent would obviously mean the pushes were not sent, wouldn't it? On the other hand I get the gcm messages, so pushes seem to be received *somehow*.

Comment: Put your `IntentService` code please, it probably doesn't accept `CANCELLED` messages.

Comment: Using com.parse.PushService, added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "solve" this by downgrading parse-server npm package to version 1.6.

See also: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1151

Seems that the push id is missing.